# how can I make fill colors change for every category to highlight a rows?

Tags: google-sheets

I am making a todo list using Google Spreadsheet. I have three categories for each task. iOS, Android and both are all under the platform column. How can I assign fill colors for each of the categories under platform so that a given color will highlight a row once I enter the platform type?

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional formatting and for the field that says "Apply to range" you only put the reference to the rows:

```
'2:1000'
```